# EF Core dynamic lambda subquery not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a problem with some dynamically created `IQueriable<T>` that later is used as subquery to another query.I'll try to explain:

I use a method that returns the `IQueryable`:

```cs
private IQueryable<ProcessValueBase> GetQuery(string period, DeviceModel device)
        {
            var predicatePv = PredicateBuilder.New<ProcessValueModel>()
                .And(pv => pv.TagSettings.DeviceId == device.Id)
            .And(GetSetpointCommonExpression<ProcessValueModel>(GetSetpointTagTypeId(device.DeviceTypeId)));
            var predicateNv = PredicateBuilder.New<NormalizedLogValueModel>()
                .And(pv => pv.TagSettings.DeviceId == device.Id)
            .And(GetSetpointCommonExpression<NormalizedLogValueModel>(GetSetpointTagTypeId(device.DeviceTypeId)));

            var utcTime = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
            switch (period)
            {
                case TimePeriodType.Current:
                    return dbContext.ProcessValues.Where(predicatePv);
                case TimePeriodType.Day:
                    var startOfDay = utcTime.StartOfDay();
                    predicateNv = predicateNv.And(v => v.Timestamp >= startOfDay && v.Timestamp < startOfDay.AddDays(1));
                    break;
                case TimePeriodType.Week:
                    var startOfWeek = utcTime.FirstDayOfWeek();
                    predicateNv = predicateNv.And(v => v.Timestamp >= startOfWeek && v.Timestamp < startOfWeek.AddDays(7));
                    break;
                case TimePeriodType.Month:
                    var startOfMonth = utcTime.FirstDayOfMonth();
                    predicateNv = predicateNv.And(v => v.Timestamp >= startOfMonth && v.Timestamp < startOfMonth.AddMonths(1));
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return dbContext.NormalizedLogValues.Where(predicateNv);
        }
```

Then I use it in my main query:

```cs
var res = dbContext.Rooms.Select(r => new
            {
                RoomId = r.Id,
                ZoneId = r.ZoneId,
                IdealSetpoint = r.Group.Setpoints.First(sp => sp.ClimaticZoneId == dbContext.ClimaticZonesLogs.OrderByDescending(cz => cz.Timestamp).First().ClimaticZoneId).Setpoint,
                Devices = r.Devices
                .Select(rd => rd.Device)
                .Select(d => new
                {
                    Id = d.Id,
                    Name = d.Name,
                    //Here is the problem
                    Setpoint = GetQuery(req.Period, d).Average(t => t.Value)
                })
            }
            ).ToList();
```

The exception that I get is:

```
The LINQ expression 'SetpointSideViewHandler.GetQuery(
    period: __req_Period_0, 
    device: NavigationTreeExpression
        Value: EntityReference: DeviceModel
        Expression: d.Inner)
    .Average(t => t.Value)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.
```

Is anybody have a clue, why I'm getting this error?

Thanks in advance,

Julian

Comment: You don' t say what LINQ provider you're using, but in general LINQ providers aren't *magic*; there will always be a limit to how interesting the C# is that they can successfully convert to run on the store

Comment: You basically can't call /any/ function within a `.Select` and expect it to run on the server.  If you put your GetQuery code inline, I bet it will work

Comment: @Neil the thing is that I need to "take" information from different `DbSet<T>` from the context, based on the (in my case) `d` in the second `.Select`. But yes I got your point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Neil said in the comments, we can't put any function call in `.Select`:

> You basically can't call /any/ function within a .Select and expect it to run on the server. If you put your GetQuery code inline, I bet it will work

Putting the code inline, solve the problem