# How to run dynamic query containing subquery with EF Core?

Tags: entity-framework-core, subquery

I'm able to run all sorts of dynamically composed queries with EF Core **except when containing sub-queries**.

Hence, this is not a duplicate of [EF Core dynamic lambda subquery not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66674049) or any other I was able to find for that matter.

A runnable repro to demonstrate the issue can be found on [dotnetfiddle.net/4opEqr](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4opEqr) that uses a dynamically composed expression representing the following query:

```
efContext.Products.Where(p => p.Id == efContext.OrderItem.Max(i => i.ProductId)).ToList();
```

The exception I get is

```
System.InvalidOperationException : The LINQ expression 'InternalDbSet<OrderItem> {  }
    .Max(i => i.ProductId)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

I observe the same behaviour with *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer* as with *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory* (versions 6.0.8 and 7.0.0-preview.7.22376.2).

Comment: What are you trying to build? `DistinctBy`?

Comment: This is just a brief example to demo the issue that seems to apply to any subquery.

Comment: For background info: here's my motivation for the question https://github.com/6bee/Remote.Linq/issues/112

Comment: Looks like you are trying to fix issue with Remote.Linq serialisation?

Comment: @IvanStoev, not `Relinq` but `Remote.Linq`. Two cardinally different libraries with different purpose.

Comment: @IvanStoev, good to know that you can execute LINQ queries via network. I it is hard to imagine practical usage, but sometimes it is needed. Answered similar question 2 years ago when OP was trying to execute SQL generated by EF via TCP/IP and return result back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be both the way EF Core processes nested queryable expressions inside expression tree, and the way you are trying to test the dynamic expressions you create.

Shortly, here

```cs
productQueryable.Where(p => p.Id == orderItemQueryable.Max(i => i.ProductId))
```

`productQueryable` is regular variable (and `.Where` is regular call) and `orderItemQueryable` is compiler generated closure (as part of the queryable `Where` predicate expression), while here

```cs
() => productQueryable.Where(p => p.Id == orderItemQueryable.Max(i => i.ProductId))
```

they both are compiler generated closures.

So, the EF Core does not correctly process `Constant` expression holding nested queryable variable value inside "root" query expression, so for subqueries you should either pass directly `IQueryable.Expression` property value, or simulate closure (but not constant) expression. While for root queryable you should either wrap it in constant expression, or in simulated closure (but not directly).

Since wrapping the queryable variables work for both cases, the solution is to always wrap such variables in closure emulating expression. And closure emulating expression is any expression which contains constant expression holding some class instance holding the actual variable inside class property or field.

It can be implemented in several ways, for instance using `System.Tuple` class as holder:

```cs
static Expression MakeClosure<T>(T value)
{
    var closure = new Tuple<T>(value);
    return Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(closure), nameof(closure.Item1));
}
```

or real compiler generated closure class instance:

```cs
static Expression MakeClosure<T>(T value)
{
    var closure = new { value };
    return Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(closure), nameof(closure.value));
}
```

or the same using the body of compiler generated lambda expression containing closure:

```cs
static Expression MakeClosure<T>(T value)
{
    Expression<Func<T>> lambda = () => value;
    return lambda.Body;
}
```

Finally, in all the cases change the sample code as

```cs
var productQueryableExp = MakeClosure(productQueryable);
var orderItemQueryableExp = MakeClosure(orderItemQueryable);
```

and everything will work as expected. At least with EF Core. What about the other library you seem to be using (Remote.Linq), have no idea (that's I guess would be another question).